# Joining a table and 2 linker tables

Tags: sql

I've been working on this for 2 days while relearning the limited amount of SQL I ever knew, but I just can't pull this off. My SQL skills are weak at best and not often used.  I know the database isn't properly normalized, but my tables are not likely to have more than a few hundred entries and performance is the least of my concerns.  If the query takes 5 or more minutes to run, I couldn't care less at this point :).

I have 3 tables:

```
UserTable:     GroupTable:     ShareTable:
  username       GroupName       ShareName
  realname       username        UserOrGroup
  status                         PermissionLevel
```

By Request, data in tables:

```
  username     realname     status
   jdoe         John Doe     Active
   jAdoe        Jane Doe     Active


  groupname     username
   usersgroup    jdoe
   usersgroup    jAdoe
   admingroup    jdoe
   admingroup    jAdoe


  sharename     userorgroup     permissionlevel
   finance       jdoe            read/write
   allstaff      usersgroup      read/write
   admin         admingroup      read
   admin         jAdoe           read/write
```

What I want is to see who has access to each share, what their current status is, and what their permission level is on the share.   If that access is based on a group membership, I want to see the group name, otherwise, I'd like that column to be NULL.  Something like this:

```
 Real Name     Status     ShareName     Permission     GroupName
   John Doe      Active     Finance       Read/Write     NULL
   John Doe      Active     AllStaff      Read/Write     UsersGroup
   John Doe      Active     Admin         Read           AdminGroup
   Jane Doe      Active     Admin         Read/Write     NULL
   Jane Doe      Active     Admin         Read           AdminGroup
   Jane Doe      Active     AllStaff      Read/Write     UsersGroup
```

John's access to finance is explicitly assigned, his allstaff access is due to his membership in UsersGroup, etc.....

This is getting me close, but I'm getting some duplicates, and not getting my nulls.

```
SELECT 
  u.realName,
  u.status, 
  s.ShareName,
  s.Permissionlevel,
  ug.GroupName

FROM dbo.usertable AS u
   INNER JOIN dbo.Sharestable AS s
   ON u.UserName = s.UserOrGroup 
   INNER JOIN dbo.grouptable as ug
   ON u.UserName = ug.UserName
   INNER JOIN dbo.Sharestable as s2
   ON s2.UserOrGroup = ug.GroupName

 ORDER BY u.realName
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  I've tried reordering things playing with right and left joins.  I guess the next step is to experiment with sub queries, but I'm a bit burned out on the problem ATM.  I learned a lot getting to this point, can someone push me over the finish line?

Comment: Can you show the sample data in the tables.  It looks like you're missing a `LEFT Join` for the `Null` issue, but not sure on dups.

Comment: I edited in some sample table data.

Comment: I finally had to give up on SQL and brute force it with powershell to get the project completed.  I might take another shot at doing this with SQL next month when I have to redo the report, so

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are getting duplicate values then using **DISTINCT** with the query might help you in not getting the duplicate results..